# Is it possible to create a rule for etc hosts (Rule: 10.0.0.* ip. Usage: ping ip.10)?

Tags: networking, hosts

If I have multiple hosts I want to add aliases for, e.g.

```
10.0.0.10 ip_10
10.0.0.11 ip_11
10.0.0.12 ip_12
```

Is there a way to have a group these into one line?

I tried

```
10.0.0. ip
```

and then tried to ping it with `ping ip.10` but that gave `ping: unknown host ip.10`.

I also tried `10.0.0.*    ip.*`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The format of [`/etc/hosts`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man5/hosts.5.html) is very simple and doesn't allow for complex pattern matching:

```
This  manual page describes the format of the /etc/hosts file.  This file is a simple text
file that associates IP addresses with hostnames, one line per IP address.  For each  host
a single line should be present with the following information:

      IP_address canonical_hostname [aliases...]

Fields  of  the  entry  are separated by any number of blanks and/or tab characters.  Text
from a "#" character until the end of the line is a comment, and is ignored.   Host  names
may contain only alphanumeric characters, minus signs ("-"), and periods (".").  They must
begin with an alphabetic character and  end  with  an  alphanumeric  character.   Optional
aliases  provide  for  name  changes,  alternate  spellings, shorter hostnames, or generic
hostnames (for example, localhost).
```

BIND apparently supports [something like this](https://serverfault.com/a/133727/229499), in case you want to try that.